# Pycharm says me that there I have misstake (Expected type 'Typ', got 'dict[str, int | str]' instead )

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im beginner in python and I just dont understand that warning and why Pycharm writing that simbol after int - ('|'). Also full text of warning is in the comment. Thanks in advance

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Typ(TypedDict):
    word: str
    count: int
    comment: str


dict_result: Typ = {'word': 'hello', 'count': 12, 'comment': 'yo'}###(Expected type 'Typ', got 
                                                              #'dict[str, int | str]' instead)
print(dict_result['word'])
print(dict_result['count'])
print(dict_result['comment'])
```

Comment: Works very well for me , [edit] your post and add version of pycharm and python used

Comment: Aside: the `int | str` is just indicating that it was detected that the values of the dictionary contain both types. It has nothing to do with your actual problem.